Zabbix 6.4 interface traps down/up clearing trigger doesnt work
I am new to Zabbix and at the moment losing my mind how to setup trigger for receiving snmp traps interface up /down to work properly.
both snmptraps, interface down and up, I am receiving but recovery process is not working properly. In some cases does, in some not. I've changed trigger conf x times but unsuccessfully.

trigger configuration:
problem expression
find(/SNMP Interface Traps/snmptrap["\s.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3"],,"regexp","down")=1 and nodata(/SNMP Interface Traps/snmptrap["\s.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3"],10s)=0
recovery expression
find(/SNMP Interface Traps/snmptrap["\s.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.4"],,"regexp","up")=1  and nodata(/SNMP Interface Traps/snmptrap["\s.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.4"],20s)=0

ok event closed if tag is matched which is
Interface Name regex : {{ITEM.VALUE}.regsub("\s+\"(.*?)\"(.*)", "\1")}
----------------------------------------
example of trap (regex is working ok)
07:21:22 2024/08/30 ZBXTRAP 86.32.0.22  PDU INFO:         errorindex                     0        transactionid                  14010555         receivedfrom                   UDP: [11.32.0.22]:161->[11.18.68.16]:162         version                        1        errorstatus                    0        messageid                      0        requestid                      1933     community
public   notificationtype               TRAP   
VARBINDS          .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0             type=67 value=Timeticks: (692945454) 80 days, 4:50:54.54         .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0         type=6  value=OID: .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3   .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.96        type=2  value=INTEGER: 96        .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.96        type=4  value=STRING: "Bundle-Ether3"    .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.96        type=2  value=INTEGER: 53         .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.276.1.1.2.1.3.96 type=4  value=STRING: "down"

I search a lot of forums and documentation but didnt find answer.can anyone help me? thx!
br
